# DynanoDB streams behavior after repartition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am assuming that reading from DynamoDB streams using the Kinesis library will give me always ordered sequence of events for records with the same partition key.

Is that correct?

If a repartition happens, will the library still give me ordered records for all the table activity for the same partition key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the ordered sequence question: yes, you will read the updates in time sequence order.  From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html):

> DynamoDB Streams captures a time-ordered sequence of item-level modifications in any DynamoDB table, and stores this information in a log for up to 24 hours. Applications can access this log and view the data items as they appeared before and after they were modified, in near real time.

A repartition is just another type of table update and the log file will not be modified for older updates.  So yes, you will read the same order for the updates after the repartition.